# Skyrim characters before installing Dawnguard

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

If I started a character before downloading Dawnguard, will my character still be able to become a vampire lord?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to still become a vampire lord before downloading Dawnguard.
Just simply go through the quest line when you download it and you will get to the opportunity to become a vampire lord.

Answer (score 0):

You will absolutely be able to do either quest line (Dawnguard or Vampire Lord) with old characters, but as always your character must be level 10 to trigger the first quest (Note: I am only sure of this for PC, but other people could confirm for consoles).

However, be aware that a high level character will have no problem doing these quests whereas a level 10 character might struggle.  If you find that it is too hard or too easy for your character I recommend changing the difficulty to make it more suitable.  For example, I played through the Dawnguard side starting as a level 40 wood elf archer/assassin, and I had to play on Master difficulty for it to be challenging enough.

Happy Hunting!